# Instance of a class updates a variable, and all the other instances get updated as well. Why?

Tags: python

Consider the following code, hopefully self-explanatory:

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, id:int, info=dict()) -> None:
        self.id = id
        self.info = info

a1, a2 = Agent(1), Agent(2)
a1.info['object'] = 'property'
print(a1.info)
print(a2.info)
```

The output is:

```
{'object': 'property'}
{'object': 'property'}
```

What?! Agent 1 learns something new, and Agent 2 magically comes to know it as well. Weird.

Why does this happen?

I can make this effect go away, but the tweaks feel arbitrary. For instance, removing the `=dict()` declaration from the `__init__` header seems to work. But I don't like this, because then I have to initialize every agent with an empty dictionary as prior knowledge; I'd prefer it if it was implicitly assumed that agents start out with zero knowledge.

Another thing that works is updating Agent 1's knowledge as follows:

```
a1.info = {'object':'property'}
```

Still though: why does the initial code behave as it does? Explain like I'm five, please?

Comment: See the duplicate, but the gist of it is: `info` is the same dict. The correct way to initialize a mutable argument would be `... info=None): if info is None: info = {}`.

Comment: Oh ok, cool! Thanks. I still wouldn't delete the question, though, as it may be of use to someone coming at it as I did. Also, the duplicate is a bit abstruse (and patronizing).